# Magento 2 CSS doesnt generate static/_cache folder and throw a "blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch" error

Tags: magento2

Here the whole error message:
The resource from “https://example.com/static/_cache/merged/423594d2c9a788a2af3e706167e88c9f.min.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Context:
I had an existing project to debug. Everything went well in local environment. I deployed in staging; everything went well too. In production I got the MIME type error when deploying. The front-end is ok, I only got this in back-end.

Project is on Magento 2.1.1.
Production is on NGINX.
Everywhere else on apache.

I know that they were an attempts to upgrade to 2.3.1 and it was rollbacked.

I'm deploying using this procedure:

1. Checkout branch
2. Composer update
3. bin/magento
4. rm -rf var/cache/*
5. rm -rf var/page_cache/*
6. rm -rf var/generation/*
7. rm -rf pub/static/*
8. rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
9. rm -rf var/di/*
10. rm -rf generated/code/* generated/metadata/*
11. php bin/magento maintenance:enable
12. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
13. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
14. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
15. php bin/magento maintenance:disable
16. php bin/magento cache:flush
17. find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
18. find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
19. find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
20. chmod -R 777 ./pub/media/
21. chmod -R 777 ./pub/static/
22. chmod 777 ./app/etc
23. chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

I get no errors anywhere, except the one above in the browser console.

If you could have any hint for me, I'm lost! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because it ends up in a 404. In my case I fixed it by changing

`web/secure/base_static_url` and `web/secure/base_static_url`

from
`{{secure_base_url}}static/` and `{{secure_base_url}}static/`

to
`{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/` and `{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/` respectively.

I'm not sure exactly why it is served from the pub folder in this case while my other Magento projects don't have this and I suspect it's a Valet or Nginx misconfiguration in my own case.